# Htaccess rewrite query string to another query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Trying to make redirects:

```
domain.com/search/?q=query&p=2
domain.com/niche/?q=weddings&p=2
domain.com/tag/?q=rings&p=2
```

to

```
domain.com/index.php?search=query&page=2
domain.com/index.php?group_name=weddings&page=2
domain.com/index.php?tag=rings&page=2
```

without changing url.

Using this rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^/]+)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^search/$ index.php?search=%1&page=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^/]+)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^niches/$ index.php?group_name=%1&page=%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^/]+)&p=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^tag/$ index.php?tag=%1&page=%2 [L]
```

Search and Niches are working good, and Tag is giving 404. However, sraight url (like domain.com/index.php?tag=rings&page=2) is working great. Can you please help to figure out? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a folder "tag"? It contains maybe another htaccess (hidden file).

Comment: nope, no "tag" folder :(

Comment: did you check access.log?

Comment: What url is causing the 404 error? Post a complete example of the url.

Comment: `URL /index.php?tag=dresses&page=2` is OK
`URL /tag/?q=dresses&p=2` is 404